# Correct way to apply chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let $f(x,y) = x + x^2 + y$, we have $f_x(x,y) = 1 + 2x$.

Let $u = x^2$ and write $f(x,y,u) = x+ u +y$.
When applying the chain rule, $f_x(x,y,u) = f_u(x,y,u)(du/dx) + f_y(x,y,u) (dy/dx) + f_x(x,y,u) (dx/dx)$. It then becomes tempting to cancel the LHS with the last term of RHS to get $f_u(x,y,u)(du/dx) + f_y(x,y,u)(dy/dx) = 0$. The problem is that the RHS $f_x(x,y,u)$ means to keep $y,u$ as fixed constants while the LHS has $u = u(x)$.

To tackle this problem, I write $f_x(x,y,u) = f_u(x,y,u)|_{x,y}(du/dx) + f_y(x,y,u)|_{x,u} (dy/dx) + f_x(x,y,u)|_{y,u} (dx/dx)$ to note which variables are fixed for each partial derivative. My question: is this correct? And is there anything else I need to watch out for when applying the chain rule using this formula?

Comment: You have a problem with the notation you are using. Typically, $f_x$ means the partial derivative with respect to a variable, here the first one (using $x$ here is already causing confusion) - this is the term appearing on the right hand side. What you seem to intend to write on the left hand side is the so called total derivative with respect to $x$, usually written as $df/dx$

Comment: Also it's a bad idea to use the same letter $f$ for two different functions.

Comment: The second function shouldn’t be called $f.$ $g(x,y,u)=x+y+u,$ and $f(x,y)=g(x,y,x^2).$

Comment: @Thomas I'm confused, everywhere I look, the chain rule is $\frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial {t_i}}} = \frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial {x_1}}}\frac{{\partial {x_1}}}{{\partial {t_i}}} + \frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial {x_2}}}\frac{{\partial {x_2}}}{{\partial {t_i}}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{\partial z}}{{\partial {x_n}}}\frac{{\partial {x_n}}}{{\partial {t_i}}}$, should the LHS be $\frac{dz}{dt_i}$ instead? Where $\frac{dz}{dt_i}$ means the total derivative wrt $t_i$?

Comment: In general, is there only two cases of the chain rule? In one case, we have $f(x,y,z)$, $x,y,z$ depend on $u,v$ and we want the partial wrt to $u$. The other case is like the one I have where we have $f(x,y,z)$, $y,z$ may depend on $x,t$ and we want the partial derivative wrt to $x$. The LHS of the chain rule in this case means "keep no variable constant" and the partials in the RHS of the chain rule means "keep both y,z constant"?

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4296438?

Comment: The response by Arthur in https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/19001/what-is-the-right-notation-to-use-in-multivariable-chain-rules answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You denote two different functions by the same symbol $f$, the two-variable function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R , f(x,y) = x + x^2 + y$, and the three-variable function $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R , f(x,y,u) = x+ u +y$. This must not be done, write e.g. $F : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R ,F(x,y,u) = x + y + u$.

Define $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3, g(x,y) = (x,y,x^2)$. Then $f = F \circ g$. We can now apply the chain rule of multivariable analysis. Let us do it via the Jacobians of $F$ and $g$. We have

$$JF(x_0,y_0,u_0) = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0,u_0)\phantom{x} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} (x_0,y_0,u_0) \phantom{x} \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(x_0,y_0,u_0)\\ 
\end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
1 \phantom{x} 1 \phantom{x} 1 \\ 
\end{array}\right),$$
$$Jg(x_0,y_0) = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) & \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)  \\ 
\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) \\
\frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) & \frac{\partial g_3}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) \\ 
\end{array}\right) =  \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0  \\ 
0 & 1 \\
2x_0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}\right)$$
where $g_1(x,y) = x , g_2(x,y) = y, g_3(x,y) = x^2$ are the component functions of $g$. It seems that you write $\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x} = \frac{dx}{d x}$, $\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x} = \frac{dy}{d x}$ etc. which is **not correct**. You must again distinguish the two-variable functions $g_i$ from the one-variable functions $x, y, u$. Moreover, the expression $\frac{dy}{d x}$ only makes sense if $y$ is a function of $x$, and that is not true.

The chain rule says that (where $\cdot$ is matrix mutliplicaton)
$$Jf(x_0,y_0) = JF(g(x_0,y_0)) \cdot Jg(x_0,y_0) = 
 \\  = (1 +2x_0 \phantom{x} 1) = \left( \begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\phantom{x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x_0,y_0)\\ 
\end{array}\right)$$
which is no surprise. Omitting the arguments $(x_0,y_0)$ and $g(x_0,y_0) = (x_0,y_0,x_0^2)$ we have on the abstract level
$$\left( \begin{array}{rrr}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \phantom {xxx} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\ 
\end{array}\right) = Jf = JF \cdot Jg \\= 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial g_3}{\partial x} \phantom {xxx} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial g_3}{\partial y}\\ 
\end{array}\right)$$