# Taking the partial derivative of both sides of an equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, euler-lagrange-equation

I have this function: $G(x, y, z) = G(x, y, g(x,y))$ and the equation $$G = 0$$

I want to reach a specific equation:
$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{g}}*\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} = 0$$

I can see that by taking the total derivative in respect to y on the starting equation takes me to this equation:
$$\frac{dG}{dy} = 
\nabla{G} * \begin{pmatrix}\frac{dx}{dy} & \frac{dy}{dy} & \frac{dg}{dy}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} & \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{g}}\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}}\end{pmatrix} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{g}}*\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} = 0$$

Another idea is to take the partial derivate:
$$G = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}= 0$$
$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}= 0$$
$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{g}}= 0$$
And exchange the order of differentiation.
$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}} + \frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{g}} \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}}= 0$$
Exchanging the order of differentiation seems wrong to me, but
$$G = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{y}}= 0$$
seems wrong as well. Can we not take the partial derivative of both sides on an equation?

Comment: Properly, we take partial derivatives of _functions_, not of _equations_. In any case, the issue appears to be the use of the single symbol $G$ to denote two distinct functions: (i) A function of three variables $G(x, y, z)$ that presumably is not identically zero; (ii) a function of two variables $H(x, y) = G(x, y, g(x, y))$ that is identically zero.

Comment: sorry, z = g(x,y) so H = G. Does this mean that the partial derivative of G with respect to y is _not_ 0?

Comment: The condition $z = g(x, y)$ was clear, but again, $H$ and $G$ are not the same function; they don't even depend on the same number of variables. What you're really computing is the partial of $H$ with respect to $y$, which is zero because $H$ is zero, and is expressed in terms of partials of $G$ by the chain rule in your first calculation. As you say, the partial of $G$ with respect to $y$ is not zero.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It would be great if you posted it as an answer so I can close this question.

Comment: This type of question has been answered elsewhere on site. Marking the following as a prospective duplicate: [Partial derivatives seem to depend on how variables are defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296438/partial-derivatives-seem-to-depend-on-how-variables-are-defined)